# Past date shows for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE()

Tags: sql-server, date

Why is that that suddenly in SQL Server Management Studio when I query `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()`, it gives me a past date?

```
SELECT 
    SYSDATETIME() ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() ,SYSUTCDATETIME() ,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,GETDATE() ,GETUTCDATE()
```

[image]

`SYSDATETIME()` and `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` and `SYSUTCDATETIME()` gives back the correct date, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()` shows past dates.

I had read something here about replicas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015272/getdate-in-sql-server-2019-giving-wrong-date), but I don't have replication.

[image]

How can I fix it to show the same dates as before?

Comment: What happens if you start a new transaction?

Comment: You ask why does this happen in SSMS; does this mean that this behaviour *only* occurs in SSMS, and no other environments? If you run the query from ADS, `sqlcmd`, or from your application you don't get the behaviour?

Comment: The screenshot of the data doesn't help ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)), @GuidoG , but according to it, they are *completely* different values that are *days* apart.

Comment: More than a month apart. 840 hours, 42 mins

Comment: the answer you linked is wrong anyway. `GETDATE()` is just a Windows API call. The documentation linked in that answer states "This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.". There is no independently derived "database system timestamp"

Comment: Is your server running on Windows or Linux? Any answer to @Larnu's question as to whether this is reproducible in other clients than SSMS?

Comment: Looks to be a Windows Server, @MartinSmith . From the screenshot you can *just* see the green from the icon for the server. Linux servers have a Little Tux instead.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear enough. I am a bit new using these tools.
My server is running on Windows. The first 3 columns shows the correct date by the month and day, but the last 3 columns shows past dates.
I have no other environments, I have only one installation on my local computer.
From my application I get the same wrong date when I execute the query.
Previously I had no issues like this, but as from today, the select gives back past date (05.26) for the last 3 columns.

Comment: no I am not using it

Comment: If you rerun the query are the last three values stuck at those times or do they change?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have checked the obvious, like that the date of the computer where sql server is installed and running is correct ?

Comment: Possibly related, for both Windows and Linux systems (containered or otherwise)... [Time freezes upon suspend (ubuntu) - GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE() #654](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/654)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nice find. `SYSDATETIME` is documented to use  `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` API. [Ed Elliott here](https://sqlserverfunctions.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/how-does-select-getdate-work/) has experimented with a debugger and says  `GETDATE` uses `GetLocalTime` API call - I don't see any complaints about that specific method when googling it though

Comment: And that test was done in 2014 - it is possible things have changed since then as the github seems to indicate problems since 2019

Comment: I don't know what happened, but after restarting my computer, the dates (month and day) are now correct for all columns.
I haven't experienced this behaviour :/

Comment: Looks like the same issue that AlwaysLearning found - where some of these functions get messed up after suspending the OS for reasons unexplained in that link